# Dynamic array with angular

Tags: arrays, angular, dynamic, observable

Basically I have an api that returns data when I do a search, I push them into an array and I display them by doing an ngFor in my html.

When I want to do a new search it's the same function that is called, but the html is not updated while I get new data.

It always appears the old data recovered the first time.

To search, i used this code :

SearchBar.component.ts

```
export class RechercheToutComponent implements OnInit {

  searchInput = new FormControl('');

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private recherche: RechercheComponent
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  search() {
    if(this.router.url.match(/recherche.*!/)){
      this.recherche.searchResult(this.searchInput.value)
    }else{
      this.router.navigate(['/recherche'], {queryParams: {search: this.searchInput.value}}).then(r => this.recherche.searchResult(this.searchInput.value))
    }
  }
}
```

SearBar.component.html

```
<form class="catalogue-search-form" (ngSubmit)="search()">
  <div class="search-bar">
    <input type="text"
           [formControl]="searchInput"
           placeholder="Rechercher dans Intra"
    />
    <button type="submit" class="text-button">
      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Search.component.ts

```
export class RechercheComponent implements OnInit {

  searchParam: any;

  results$: Observable<Array<any>>;

  isResultLoading: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.searchParam = params['search']
    });
    this.searchResult(this.searchParam);
  }

  searchResult(searchParam) {
    this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/Recherchetout.php`, {params: {search: searchParam}}).subscribe(
      (data: Array<any>) => {
        this.results$ = of(data)
        this.isResultLoading = false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Search.component.html

```
<div class="recherche">
  <div class="spinner-search" *ngIf="isResultLoading">
    <app-spinner></app-spinner>
  </div>
  <div class="content" *ngIf="!isResultLoading">
    <div *ngFor="let oui of results$ | async">
      <div *ngIf="oui.produit != undefined">
        {{ oui.produit.pdf }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I tried to create observables but it didn't work, with a simple array too.

So my question is: Why is my data not updating on my html?
And how to do it ?

Sorry in advance for the mistakes, or for the disastrous code I begin in angular

Comment: Looks like `searchResult` is only called on ngOnInit and not every time the `searchParam` is updated so it shows the old results. If you can created a Stackblitz example, it'll be easier to suggest code changes.

Comment: that is because you are creating for each result a new obseravble but the async pipe is still references the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are injecting `RechercheComponent` inside the SearchBar component, angular will create different instance than the one used on the UI.

to send data between multiple components create a parent component and use it to allow communication between the two components (use the Input and Output attributes).

make your system navigate to the parent then

Parent.Component.ts

```
export class ParentComponent {
  data: any[];
  isResultLoading = false;

  updateData(data: any[]) {
    this.data = data
  }
}
```

parent.component.html

```html
<app-search-bar (change)="dataChange($event)" [(isResultLoading)]="isResultLoading"></app-search-bar>
<app-search [data]="data" *ngIf="!isResultLoading"></app-search>
```

update your Search.component.ts

```
//add outputs and inputs
@Output() change = new EventEmitter<any[]>(); //make sure to import EventEmitter from @angular/core
@Input() isResultLoading : boolean

// update searchResult  subscription function
searchResult(searchParam) {
  this.isResultLoading = true;
  this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/Recherchetout.php`, { params: { search: searchParam } }).subscribe(
    (data: Array<any>) => {
      this.change.emmit(data);
      this.isResultLoading = false;
    }
  );
}
```

and finally instead of having observable result$ inside Search.component.ts
replace it with `@Input() data:Any[]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to refresh the search every time a URL change, update you `ngOnInit` by moving `this.searchResult(this.searchParam);` inside the subscribe method

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.searchParam = params['search']
      this.searchResult(this.searchParam);
    });
  }
```

with this searchResult will be called every time the router parameters get change instead of updating for the first time ngOnInit get called

Comment: In fact when I am on the search page I would like to not change the url so that the page does not refresh. I don't know if I'm clear?
And I updated the post because I forgot to put my search bar

Comment: in angular if the url change and the new url will produce the same component, angular will update the URL will keep the component intact (no visual change at the UI level for user) and will only trigger the router change

Comment: Ho ok thanks, the problem remains the same, I have the impression that if I call my function directly, the html will not take into account the last modifications.
Aren't the observables supposed to do this job of updating the data?